# Page breaks within moderncv

Tags: page-breaking, moderncv

I'm typesetting a document with lengthy `itemize` lists and in most cases LaTeX leaves lots of empty space before the environment in order to get it entirely on one page.

How can I encourage LaTeX to put page breaks within lists?

**Update:** I found that it works just fine when used not within `\cventry` command.

Is there anyway to fix `\cventry` definition in order to avoid non-breaking behavior?

From `moderncvstylebanking.sty`:

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}%
      {\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5} \\%
      {\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\itshape #2}\\%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\\\vbox{\small#7}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

**Examples:** Originally I've used `\cventry` in the following way:

```
\cventry{March 2009--April 2011}{Software Developer}{Company}{City}{}{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1;
        % Lots of items here
        \item Item n.
    \end{itemize}
}
```

Probably I'm just misusing `\cventry` because using the following makes it just fine:

```
\cventry{March 2009--April 2011}{Software Developer}{Company}{City}{}{}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1;
    % Lots of items here
    \item Item n.
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: LaTeX puts `\@itempenalty` between items but this is already negative (in article class at least)  indicating that this is a good place to break. Is something else `samepage` for example setting this penalty (`samepage` sets it to the maximum penalty possible.) A MWE would help...

Comment: Your concern is just *before* `itemize`? This can be controlled via [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)'s `topsep` key-value.

Comment: @David Carlisle, I'm using `moderncv` class, but as far as I can see it also have negative `\@itempenalty`.

Comment: @Werner, I would say I concerned about not breaking the page within  `itemize` in general.

Comment: Setting content in a box (like `tabular`), as is the case with `\cventry`, keeps things together and doesn't allow breaking across the page boundary. Would you be able to supply a minimal example that highlights your use of `\cventry`?

Comment: @Werner, please see examples added.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you answered your question yourself Regent :)

In regular circumstances, you do not want the explanation / itemization that goes with a cv entry to be broken up across page. It makes reading your resume and understanding your career achievements harder, which should be avoided at all costs. So in most cases, you simply put your `itemize` environment inside the last argument of `\cventry`

For special cases where you explicitly do want to split the explanation / `itemize` over 2 pages, you put it after the `\cventry` command.
Finally, note that in these special cases and when using the `classic` or `casual` styles, you will have to do the left padding yourself. An (ugly) way around this is to manually break your input over 2 `\cventry` or `\cvitem`.

Comment: Thanks, it's great to have the answer from `moderncv` package creator!

Comment: If you use the first approach, the second part will have an alone point in the beginning of the page... `\cventry{}{}{}{}{}{ \begin{itemize} \item ABC  \end{itemize}}`

Answer (score 8):

I just discovered this problem today and ended up implementing a custom version of the `\cventry` command (dubbed `\cventrylong`) along with a customized itemize list environment `cvitemize` (via `enumitem` package):

```
% customize the enumerate environments (i.e. enumerate, itemize, ...)
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}

% A custom version of the \cventry command that supports large itemized lists
% inside argument #7 (the custom cvitemize lists should be used!)
\newcommand*{\cventrylong}[7][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
    \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} &{%
        {\bfseries#3}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    }%
  \end{tabular}%
  {\small#7}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
% A custom version of the itemize environment that sets the appropriate left
% margin for use inside \cventylong
\newlist{cvitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[cvitemize]{label=\labelitemi,%
leftmargin=\hintscolumnwidth+\separatorcolumnwidth+\labelwidth+\labelsep}
```

Using a trimmed version of `template.tex` provided by the `moderncv` package, I can demonstrate the results:

- Before:
  [image]
- After:
  [image]

Comment: This appears to be a great solution for normal cventries, but doesn't help much in this case:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181223/moderncv-pagebreak-in-cvitem

Comment: @tjanez I'm having a similar problem. I also have a section with long texts, not necessarily because of many list items.  Half of my first page is blank as your results show before change. How can I get rid of the blank?

Comment: @tjanez, your solution seems good, but it compromises the aligniment of the arguments befor the 7th (look at you screenshots). Anyway I'm interested in this solution, so could you tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: Is it possible to do without using itemize? If yes, then it answers my question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403541/break-moderncv-cventry-into-multiple-pages-without-altering-any-other-settings).

Comment: Hi @tjanez, how can I Itemize with a dash "-" instead of a bullet the nested ```\begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize}``` ?
....Indeed,  if I have ```\begin{cvitemize} ... \begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize} ... \end{cvitemize}```, both ```\cvitemize``` and ```\itemize``` show bullets... I would like bullets for ```\cvitemize``` and dash "-" for  the nested/inside```\itemize```...

Comment: @tjanez: I found my own solution about the modifications of your code, and I posted it here:
```"Itemize with a dash "-" (instead of a bullet) the nested "\itemize", and set vertical space among "\cventrylong"```
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664416/itemize-with-a-dash-instead-of-a-bullet-the-nested-itemize-and-set-ver/664582#664582

Answer (score 2):

Many document classes (notably, the standard classes `article`, `book`, and `report`, the KOMA-Script classes, `memoir`, and the AMS classes) include the code lines

```
\@lowpenalty=51
```

and

```
\@itempenalty=-\@lowpenalty
```

i.e., they set `\@itempenalty` to -51 and hereby encourage page breaks between list items. The `moderncv` class, however, only includes the second code line, i.e., the class sets `\@itempenalty` implicitly to 0. I don't know if this was done on purpose or should be considered a bug. However, try to add the following to your document preamble (EDIT: stupid mistake corrected):

```
\makeatletter
\@itempenalty=-51
\makeatother
```

Comment: Unfortunately manual setting of `\@lowpenalty` made no difference.

Comment: I think it might be a problem with the way `\cventry` is defined, because it brake the page well when it was used not within `\eventry`...

Comment: @lockstep -- don't you mean to set `\@itempenalty=-51`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks! I don't know what I was thinking. Answer edited.

Comment: @lockstep, `\@itempenalty=-51` doesn't help too.

Comment: Please see update to the question.

Comment: Does that really make LaTeX to break boxed content? AFAIU, the issue is that `\cventry` renders its stuff inside a `\tabular`.

Answer (score 2):

To complement @Xavier's answer, I post here the code of a custon defined `mcvitemize` environment, that mimics the behavior of `\cventry` for `classic` and `casual` themes.

```
\newenvironment{mcvitemize}
{%
    \addtolength{\leftmargini}{\dimexpr\hintscolumnwidth+\separatorcolumnwidth}
    \small
    \begin{itemize}
}{%
    \end{itemize}
}
```

where `\addtolength{\leftmargini}{\dimexpr\hintscolumnwidth+\separatorcolumnwidth}` controls the left padding of the items. `\hintscolumnwidth` and `\separatorcolumnwidth` are lengths defined by the `modenrcv` class.

To use it simply add the code to the preamble and then do

```
\cventry{March 2009--April 2011}{Software Developer}{Company}{City}{}{}
\begin{mcvitemize}
    \item Item 1;
    % Lots of items here
    \item Item n.
\end{mcvitemize}
```

Comment: Hi @Alessandro Cuttin, your solution leaves (i) a significant vertical space between ```{city}``` and the list of ```\item```, and (ii) no space between two ```\cventry```. Any solution to adjust those vertical spaces ?