# moderncv - how to let points in itemize move to next page?

Tags: moderncv

How can I make it such that the elements within each `cventry` fills up available space and not get pushed over to the next page because there is insufficient space on the current page. In the image below (I removed some items that are private), the entire entry on Advanced Digital Sciences Center has been moved to the next page when there is sufficient space on the current page to hold at least the titles.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.6cm}
\recomputelengths

\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\footnotesize }

% personal datas
\firstname{Haziq}
\familyname{Razali}
\address{Bukit Batok West Ave 6 \\ Block 189 \#15-27 \\ Singapore 650189 \\}{}
\mobile{(+65) 9172-2319}              
%\email{ha\_haziq\_91@hotmail.com} 
\extrainfo{ \\ ha\_haziq\_91@hotmail.com\\
}
}
\photo[84pt]{Haziq.jpg}

\AtBeginDocument{
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=false,
urlbordercolor=red,
pdfborder = {0 0 1}
}
}

\nopagenumbers{} % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[rm={lining,proportional},sf={lining,proportional},tt={lining,tabular,monowidth}]{cfr-lm}
\global\let\bfseries\sbweight

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                     EDUCATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\maketitle

%Section
\section{Education}

\cventry{Aug 2013 -- Oct 2016}{Nanyang Technological University, Singapore}{}{}{}{\normalsize{B.Eng. Electrical and Electronics Engineering, 1st Class Honours} \newline{}}

\cventry{Jul 2014 -- Dec 2014}{University of Western Ontario, Canada}{}{}{}{\normalsize{Exchange Student} \newline{}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                     EXPERIENCE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Relevant Experience} 
%
\cventry{Aug 2016 -- Aug 2017}{\href{http://www.ipal.cnrs.fr/}
{Image \& Pervasive Access Lab} (Centre national de la recherche scientifique)}{\textnormal{Research Engineer}}{\textit{Object Detection in RGBD images} \vspace{2mm}}{}{
\begin{itemize}
\item AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA \vspace{3mm}
\item AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
\vspace{4mm}
\end{itemize}} 

\cventry{May 2016 -- Jul 2016}{\href{http://www.i2r.a-star.edu.sg/department/vc/index.html}
{Institute for Infocomm Research}}{\textnormal{Intern}}{\textit{Object Detection for Mobility Safety Applications} \vspace{2mm}}{}{
\begin{itemize}
\item Conducted a survey of Deep Learning methods for object detection and recognition and developed an end-to-end CNN for pedestrian detection in RGB-Thermal images \vspace{4mm} 
\end{itemize}
}

\cventry{Aug 2015 -- Apr 2016}{\href{http://adsc.illinois.edu/}
{Advanced Digital Sciences Centre} (University of Illinois at Urbana Champaign)}{\textnormal{Junior Research Assistant}}{\textit{Real Time Automated Analysis of Soccer Videos}\vspace{2mm}}{}{
\begin{itemize}
\item Designed algorithms that enhanced the ball tracker by utilizing the rules and \textit{a-priori} knowledge of soccer and implemented height estimation techniques based on the epipolar geometry of stereo vision \vspace{3mm}
\item Designed an algorithm for unsupervised learning of player-team based on k-means clustering and improved the kalman-filtering based player tracker with an occlusion handler that employed an adaptive template  \vspace{3mm}
\item Worked on camera calibration and homography for the mapping of objects onto a common coordinate system for object fusion and analysis in world coordinates \vspace{4mm}
\end{itemize}
}

\cventry{Jan 2015 -- May 2015}{Nanyang Technological University}{}{\textit{Face Recognition - Undergraduate Research Opportunities Program} \vspace{2mm}}{}{ 
\begin{itemize}
\item Conducted a detailed survey of existing techniques on 2D Face Recognition and implemented PCA and LDA on Matlab for performance evaluation \vspace{5mm}
\end{itemize}{}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                       AWARDS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Awards}

\cventry{2014  -- 2016}{\mdseries{Yayasan Mendaki - Institution of Engineers (Singapore) Scholarship}}{}{}{}{\footnotesize{The scholarship is awarded to \normalsize{\textbf{one Malay student}} per year across all engineering disciplines by nomination from NUS/NTU/SIT/SUTD\newline{}}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                   COMPUTER SKILLS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Relevant Skills \normalsize\color{black}(Proficient, \color{gray}Basic)}
\cvitem{Languages}{C++, Matlab, \color{gray} Python}
\cvitem{Libraries}{OpenCV, Point Cloud Library, OpenMP, MatConvNet, \color{gray} Caffe\newline{}}
%\cvitem{Others}{LaTeX\newline{}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                      SERVICE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{References}

\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{}

\cventry{}{Dr. Nizar Ouarti}{}{}{}{\normalsize{Associate Professor}\newline Image and Pervasive Access Lab / Université Pierre et Marie Curie \newline nizar.ouarti@ipal.cnrs.fr \newline}

\cventry{}{Dr. Lu Shijian}{}{}{}{\normalsize{Scientist II / Adjunct Assistant Professor}\newline Institute for Infocomm Research / Nanyang Technological University \newline slu@i2r.a-star.edu.sg \newline}

\cventry{}{Dr. Stefan Winkler}{}{}{}{\normalsize{Principal Research Scientist}\newline Advanced Digital Sciences Center / U. of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign \newline Stefan.Winkler@adsc.com.sg \newline}

\closesection{}                   % needed to renewcommands

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add your code instead of posting images. People here can reproduce your problem and give you a hand.

Comment: Hi i have edited my post to include the code

Comment: Does anyone have any solution ? I tried the solution at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46123/page-breaks-within-moderncv i.e. to put the itemize after cventry but now i am unsure how i can pad it

Comment: ,@kong -- This is a design issue in `moderncv` class, as it internally uses a `tabular` to build each `cvitem`. A `tabular` cannot break across pages. My advice is to use your own design because this one is so popular that it won't make you noticed in a crowd.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your question,  first of all your given code does **not** result in the image you showed us.  Second has class `moderncv` some restrictions you can only hardly bypass ...

If you want to control where a new page has to be started just add command `\clearpage` or `\newpage` in your code.  Then the page break will happen where you wrote the command.

Class `moderncv` is sometimes not able to automaticaly create "good" page breakings for reasons, that lays in the kind the class has been build. The best way to overcome this is to completely create the page breaks by your own!

Or use another class which better fits your needs ...

Your code (I only added option `showframe` to display used typing area and margins)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}

\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[%
  scale=0.75,
  showframe,  % <=======================================================
]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.6cm}
\recomputelengths

\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\footnotesize }

% personal datas
\firstname{Haziq}
\familyname{Razali}
\address{Bukit Batok West Ave 6 \\ Block 189 \#15-27 \\ Singapore 650189 \\}{}
\mobile{(+65) 9172-2319}              
%\email{ha\_haziq\_91@hotmail.com} 
\extrainfo{\\ ha\_haziq\_91@hotmail.com\\}
\photo[84pt]{example-image-a.jpg}% Haziq.jpg

\AtBeginDocument{
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=false,
  urlbordercolor=red,
  pdfborder = {0 0 1}
}
}

\nopagenumbers{} % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[rm={lining,proportional},sf={lining,proportional},tt={lining,tabular,monowidth}]{cfr-lm}
\global\let\bfseries\sbweight

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                     EDUCATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\maketitle

%Section
\section{Education}

\cventry{Aug 2013 -- Oct 2016}{Nanyang Technological University, Singapore}{}{}{}{\normalsize{B.Eng. Electrical and Electronics Engineering, 1st Class Honours} \newline{}}

\cventry{Jul 2014 -- Dec 2014}{University of Western Ontario, Canada}{}{}{}{\normalsize{Exchange Student} \newline{}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                     EXPERIENCE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Relevant Experience} 
%
\cventry{Aug 2016 -- Aug 2017}%
{\href{http://www.ipal.cnrs.fr/}{Image \& Pervasive Access Lab} (Centre national de la recherche scientifique)}%
{\textnormal{Research Engineer}}%
{\textit{Object Detection in RGBD images} \vspace{2mm}}{}{%
\begin{itemize}
\item AAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAA AAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAA \vspace{3mm}
\item AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA
\vspace{4mm}
\end{itemize}} 

\cventry{May 2016 -- Jul 2016}{\href{http://www.i2r.a-star.edu.sg/department/vc/index.html}
{Institute for Infocomm Research}}{\textnormal{Intern}}{\textit{Object Detection for Mobility Safety Applications} \vspace{2mm}}{}{
\begin{itemize}
\item Conducted a survey of Deep Learning methods for object detection and recognition and developed an end-to-end CNN for pedestrian detection in RGB-Thermal images \vspace{4mm} 
\end{itemize}
}

\cventry{Aug 2015 -- Apr 2016}{\href{http://adsc.illinois.edu/}
{Advanced Digital Sciences Centre} (University of Illinois at Urbana Champaign)}{\textnormal{Junior Research Assistant}}{\textit{Real Time Automated Analysis of Soccer Videos}\vspace{2mm}}{}{
\begin{itemize}
\item Designed algorithms that enhanced the ball tracker by utilizing the rules and \textit{a-priori} knowledge of soccer and implemented height estimation techniques based on the epipolar geometry of stereo vision \vspace{3mm}
\item Designed an algorithm for unsupervised learning of player-team based on k-means clustering and improved the kalman-filtering based player tracker with an occlusion handler that employed an adaptive template  \vspace{3mm}
\item Worked on camera calibration and homography for the mapping of objects onto a common coordinate system for object fusion and analysis in world coordinates \vspace{4mm}
\end{itemize}
}

\cventry{Jan 2015 -- May 2015}{Nanyang Technological University}{}{\textit{Face Recognition - Undergraduate Research Opportunities Program} \vspace{2mm}}{}{ 
\begin{itemize}
\item Conducted a detailed survey of existing techniques on 2D Face Recognition and implemented PCA and LDA on Matlab for performance evaluation \vspace{5mm}
\end{itemize}{}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                       AWARDS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Awards}

\cventry{2014  -- 2016}{\mdseries{Yayasan Mendaki - Institution of Engineers (Singapore) Scholarship}}{}{}{}{\footnotesize{The scholarship is awarded to \normalsize{\textbf{one Malay student}} per year across all engineering disciplines by nomination from NUS/NTU/SIT/SUTD\newline{}}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                   COMPUTER SKILLS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Relevant Skills \normalsize\color{black}(Proficient, \color{gray}Basic)}
\cvitem{Languages}{C++, Matlab, \color{gray} Python}
\cvitem{Libraries}{OpenCV, Point Cloud Library, OpenMP, MatConvNet, \color{gray} Caffe\newline{}}
%\cvitem{Others}{LaTeX\newline{}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                      SERVICE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{References}

\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{}

\cventry{}{Dr. Nizar Ouarti}{}{}{}{\normalsize{Associate Professor}\newline Image and Pervasive Access Lab / Université Pierre et Marie Curie \newline nizar.ouarti@ipal.cnrs.fr \newline}

\cventry{}{Dr. Lu Shijian}{}{}{}{\normalsize{Scientist II / Adjunct Assistant Professor}\newline Institute for Infocomm Research / Nanyang Technological University \newline slu@i2r.a-star.edu.sg \newline}

\cventry{}{Dr. Stefan Winkler}{}{}{}{\normalsize{Principal Research Scientist}\newline Advanced Digital Sciences Center / U. of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign \newline Stefan.Winkler@adsc.com.sg \newline}

\closesection{}                   % needed to renewcommands

\end{document}
```

gives for me the usual and (with that code) wanted result:

[image]