# Moderncv - itemize outside cventry, how to pad?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, page-breaking, moderncv

An item placed outside of `\cventry` does not get tabbed to the left. How do I align it with the main text?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.6cm}
\recomputelengths

\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\footnotesize }

% personal datas
\firstname{Haziq}
\familyname{Razali}
\address{Bukit Batok West Ave 6 \\ Block 189 \#15-27 \\ Singapore 650189 \\}{}
\mobile{(+65) 9172-2319}              
%\email{ha\_haziq\_91@hotmail.com} 
\extrainfo{ \\ ha\_haziq\_91@hotmail.com\\
\url{http://www.haziqrazali.com/}
}
\photo[84pt]{Haziq.jpg}

\AtBeginDocument{
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=false,
urlbordercolor=red,
pdfborder = {0 0 1}
}
}

\nopagenumbers{} % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[rm={lining,proportional},sf={lining,proportional},tt={lining,tabular,monowidth}]{cfr-lm}
\global\let\bfseries\sbweight

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                     EDUCATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}


\maketitle

%Section
\section{Education}

\cventry{Aug 2013 -- Oct 2016}{Nanyang Technological University, Singapore}{}{}{}{\normalsize{B.Eng. Electrical and Electronics Engineering, 1st Class Honours} \newline{}}

\cventry{Jul 2014 -- Dec 2014}{University of Western Ontario, Canada}{}{}{}{\normalsize{Exchange Student} \newline{}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                     EXPERIENCE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Relevant Experience} 
%
\cventry{Aug 2016 -- Aug 2017}{\href{http://www.ipal.cnrs.fr/}
{Image \& Pervasive Access Lab} (Centre national de la recherche scientifique)}{\textnormal{Research Engineer}}{\textit{Object Detection in RGBD images} \vspace{2mm}}{}{
\begin{itemize}
\item A \vspace{3mm}
\item A
\vspace{4mm}
\end{itemize}} 

\cventry{May 2016 -- Jul 2016}{\href{http://www.i2r.a-star.edu.sg/department/vc/index.html}
{Institute for Infocomm Research}}{\textnormal{Intern}}{\textit{Object Detection for Mobility Safety Applications} \vspace{2mm}}{}{
\begin{itemize}
\item Conducted a survey of Deep Learning methods for object detection and recognition and developed an end-to-end CNN for pedestrian detection in RGB-Thermal images \vspace{4mm} 
\end{itemize}
}

\cventry{Aug 2015 -- Apr 2016}{\href{http://adsc.illinois.edu/}
{Advanced Digital Sciences Centre} (University of Illinois at Urbana Champaign)}{\textnormal{Junior Research Assistant}}{\textit{Real Time Automated Analysis of Soccer Videos}\vspace{2mm}}{}{
\begin{itemize}
\item Designed algorithms that enhanced the ball tracker by utilizing the rules and \textit{a-priori} knowledge of soccer and implemented height estimation techniques based on the epipolar geometry of stereo vision \vspace{3mm}
\item Designed an algorithm for unsupervised learning of player-team based on k-means clustering and improved the kalman-filtering based player tracker with an occlusion handler that employed an adaptive template  \vspace{10mm}
\end{itemize}
}

\begin{itemize}
\item Worked on camera calibration and homography for the mapping of objects onto a common coordinate system for object fusion and analysis in world coordinates \vspace{4mm}
\end{itemize}

\cventry{Jan 2015 -- May 2015}{Nanyang Technological University}{}{\textit{Face Recognition - Undergraduate Research Opportunities Program} \vspace{2mm}}{}{ 
\begin{itemize}
\item Conducted a detailed survey of existing techniques on 2D Face Recognition and implemented PCA and LDA on Matlab for performance evaluation \vspace{5mm}
\end{itemize}{}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                       AWARDS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Awards}

\cventry{2014  -- 2016}{\mdseries{Yayasan Mendaki - Institution of Engineers (Singapore) Scholarship}}{}{}{}{\footnotesize{The scholarship is awarded to \normalsize{\textbf{one Malay student}} per year across all engineering disciplines by nomination from NUS/NTU/SIT/SUTD\newline{}}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                   COMPUTER SKILLS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Relevant Skills \normalsize\color{black}(Proficient, \color{gray}Basic)}
\cvitem{Languages}{C++, Matlab, \color{gray} Python}
\cvitem{Libraries}{OpenCV, Point Cloud Library, OpenMP, MatConvNet, \color{gray} Caffe\newline{}}
%\cvitem{Others}{LaTeX\newline{}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                      SERVICE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{References}

\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{}

\cventry{}{Dr. Nizar Ouarti}{}{}{}{\normalsize{Associate Professor}\newline Image and Pervasive Access Lab / Université Pierre et Marie Curie \newline nizar.ouarti@ipal.cnrs.fr \newline}

\cventry{}{Dr. Lu Shijian}{}{}{}{\normalsize{Scientist II / Adjunct Assistant Professor}\newline Institute for Infocomm Research / Nanyang Technological University \newline slu@i2r.a-star.edu.sg \newline}

\cventry{}{Dr. Stefan Winkler}{}{}{}{\normalsize{Principal Research Scientist}\newline Advanced Digital Sciences Center / U. of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign \newline Stefan.Winkler@adsc.com.sg \newline}

\closesection{}                   % needed to renewcommands

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you keep it inside the previous `\cventry`?

Comment: I have a long cventry which causes the entire segment to be shifted to the next page, leaving lots of empty spaces http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343685/moderncv-how-to-let-points-in-itemize-move-to-next-page?noredirect=1#comment843466_343685 then i saw this solution http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46123/page-breaks-within-moderncv i.e. to put items outside of cventries. So i am now stuck on adding horizontal paddings. I keep getting errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) sets the `\cventry` as an unbreakable block - a `tabular` - to achieve the display alignment. Also, the seventh argument `#7` of `\cventry` - your `itemize`d list - is set inside a `minipage` which also doesn't allow for breaking across the page boundary.

You can manually format separate items to allow for page breaking by setting them inside an empty `\cvitem{}`:

```
\cvitem{}{
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Worked on camera calibration and homography for the mapping of 
        objects onto a common coordinate system for object fusion and 
        analysis in world coordinates
  \end{itemize}
}
```

In order to allow for this to happen naturally would require a complete rewrite of that part (which is substantial).