# enumerated list in moderncv

Tags: enumerate, moderncv

Is there a way to make an enumerated list in `moderncv` that is formatted similar to `\cvlistitem`? I tried just using a regular `\begin{enumerate} ... \end{enumerate}` but then the list is aligned too far to the left rather than being aligned with the section headers as `\cvlistitem`s are.

I saw a lot of other threads here about customizing bullets in `moderncv` but most or all deal with changing the bullet style; I couldn't find anything about changing the itemize-type list to an enumerate-type list.

**Update:** Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,legalpaper,roman]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\name{Art}{Vandelay}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Work History}

\cvlistitem {\LaTeX~salesperson}
\cvlistitem {Importer/exporter}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \LaTeX~salesperson
\item Importer/exporter
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like the enumerated list to be formatted like the bulleted list.

Comment: Could you post a minimal example code?

Comment: If I understood your question correct than you can use `\cvitem{}{%
\begin{enumerate}
\item \LaTeX~salesperson
\item Importer/exporter
\end{enumerate}%
}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Perfect, didn't realize it was that simple. If you write it up as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: One more question -- what's the purpose of the % at the end of two of the lines?

Comment: OK and one more problem: Your solution doesn't seem to allow page breaks. So if the list needs to continue onto the next page, instead it puts the entire list on the next page, with a ton of white space on the preceding page. Thoughts?

Comment: @grendelsdad: The solution doesn't allow page breaks because `\cvitem` and all other derivatives putting their contents in a separate box. There are some solutions to reset a number, however it's always a manual work. Or you design a new command which uses the spaces of `cvitem`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up doing the following, hacked from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139128/63847:

```
% customize the enumerate environments (i.e. enumerate, itemize, ...)
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}

% A custom version of the enumerate environment that sets the appropriate left margin 
\newlist{cvenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[cvenumerate]{label=\arabic*.,%
leftmargin=\hintscolumnwidth+\separatorcolumnwidth+\labelwidth+\labelsep}
```