# Itemize with a dash "-" (instead of a bullet) the nested "\itemize", and set vertical space among "\cventrylong"

Tags: page-breaking, itemize, moderncv, bullets

I am trying to perform the [Page breaks within moderncv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46123/page-breaks-within-moderncv), by following the @tjanez answer (he answered on Oct 16, 2013 at 12:24):

```
% customize the enumerate environments (i.e. enumerate, itemize, ...)
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}

% A custom version of the \cventry command that supports large itemized lists
% inside argument #7 (the custom cvitemize lists should be used!)
\newcommand*{\cventrylong}[7][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
    \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} &{%
        {\bfseries#3}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    }%
  \end{tabular}%
  {\small#7}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
% A custom version of the itemize environment that sets the appropriate left
% margin for use inside \cventylong
\newlist{cvitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[cvitemize]{label=\labelitemi,%
leftmargin=\hintscolumnwidth+\separatorcolumnwidth+\labelwidth+\labelsep}
```

I have two issues:

**1 - Itemize with a dash "-" instead of a bullet the nested items in `\itemize`**

By using the @tjanez solution, both `\cvitemize` and the nested/inside `\itemize` show bullets... Instead, I would like bullets for `\cvitemize` and dash "-" for the nested/inside `\itemize`.

how can I itemize with a dash "-" instead of a bullet the nested `\begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize}`?

Please see here below an example:

```
\cventrylong{01/01/2022 -- Present}{Accountant}
{CompanyName}
{NewYork}
{}
{
\begin{cvitemize}
  \item Topic: counting money all-day
  \item Method: using a calculator
  \item Role Description: 
       \begin{itemize}
        \item I digit numbers on the calculator
        \item I write down sums and differences
       \end{itemize}
  \item 
\end{cvitemize}
}
```

**2 - How can I put a vertical space between two `\cventrylong`?**

Comment: ...Anyone who can help in this regard? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found a possible solution to my question - Obviously, any better implementation or comments are more than welcome!**

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}

% (1) A custom version of the \cventry command that supports large itemized lists
% inside argument #7 (the custom cvitemize lists should be used!)

\newcommand*{\cventrylong}[7][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
    \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} &{%
        {\bfseries#3}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}\textcolor{color1}{#4}
        % \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{{\slshape#4}}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{\newline #5} 
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{#6}%
    }%
  \end{tabular}%
  {\small#7}%
  % (2) set vertical space among "\cventrylong" - I used "1em" as space
  \par\addvspace{1em}}


% (3) A custom version of the itemize environment that sets the appropriate left margin for use inside \cventylong
\newlist{cvitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[cvitemize]{label=\labelitemi,%
leftmargin=\hintscolumnwidth+\separatorcolumnwidth+\labelwidth+\labelsep}

% (4) Itemize with a dash "-" (instead of a bullet) the nested "\itemize",  for use inside "\cventylong"
\newlist{cvitemize2}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[cvitemize2]{label=\labelitemii}
```

**Example of usage with two `\cventrylong`:**

```
\cventrylong{01/01/2021 -- 31/12/2021}{Carpenter}
{\newline{\href{https://www.company_website_1.com/}{\textcolor{color1}{Company Name 1}}}
}
{Los Angeles, USA}
{}
{
\begin{cvitemize}
  \item Topic: ....
  \item Role Description: 
       \begin{cvitemize2}
        \item \textbf{Measure, cut, and shape wood} \newline
        I performed ...
        \item \textbf{Measure, cut, and shape other materials} \newline
        I did ....
     \end{cvitemize2}
  \item Keywords: construct, ...
\end{cvitemize}
}


\cventrylong{01/01/2022 -- Present}{Accountant}
{\newline{\href{https://www.company_website_2.com/}{\textcolor{color1}{Company Name 2}}}
}
{New York, USA}
{}
{
%\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}
\begin{cvitemize}
  \item Topic: ....
  \item Role Description: 
       \begin{cvitemize2}
        \item \textbf{Count money} \newline
        I performed ...
        \item \textbf{Supervision of other employees} \newline
        I supervised ....
     \end{cvitemize2}
  \item Keywords: money, ...
\end{cvitemize}
}
```

**Here you are the final result:**

[image]